# How to force NOT NULL constraint when inserting, without affecting existing null values?

Tags: sql-server, database, constraints, schema

I have a table with a `SMALLINT` column that is currently nullable and has some null values. But no more null values should be inserted from now on.

But I also want to keep the existing null values as is, since `null` and `0` have different meanings. So I think to add a NOT NULL constraint to the column is out of options.

What kind of constraint should I use in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making the column NOT NULL (which won't work), you could add a check constraint that makes sure the value isn't NULL and then apply the check constraint with a NOCHECK option. Here's an example:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Test;

CREATE TABLE dbo.Test
(
    TestID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_dbo_Test PRIMARY KEY,
    TestName varchar(50) NULL
);
GO

INSERT dbo.Test (TestName)
VALUES ('Fred'), (NULL), ('Mary');
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Test
WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT CK_dbo_Test_TestName_not_null
CHECK (TestName IS NOT NULL);
GO

-- OK
INSERT dbo.Test (TestName)
VALUES ('Mia');
GO

-- Not OK
INSERT dbo.Test (TestName)
VALUES (NULL);
GO
```